# Is it possible to avoid local node_modules in js projects?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am exploring nodejs and js frameworks. I noticed that when I create a project, for example with `vue`

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

I get a HUGE directory named `node_modules` containing a lot of things not related to my project. Newbie in this field my only wish is to gitignore this folder or better, put it somewhere else.

Is it common to have local modules to a project? Is there a way to install all these dependencies globally or in a dedicated environment (e.g Python virtualenv)?

Comment: In short, node_modules is a place where all your project dependencies are stored. And allows you to use these dependencies in the code if you want to. And it is very common or rather always the case when a local node_modules folder is created.
You can install dependencies globally by doing 'npm install -g module_name' command

Comment: Why would it be better to put it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory does contain libraries that are required by your project - and their dependencies. From my experience, the dependencies of the libraries I'm using are about 3/4 of the folder size.

You can install a library globally using the `-g` switch of `npm`, I'm not sure if `vue` has similar option. But this is **not recommended** - the point of installing libraries with your project is that the project will remember which libraries belong to it, those are saved in `package.json`.

You could copy the `node_modules` directory to the root of your hard-drive and merge it with other `node_modules` directories, but you're risking that you'll mix different library versions that way, so this is not recommended.

Unless you're running low on free space, just leave it be. Remember to add the `node_modules` to `.gitignore` if you're using git.

Answer (score 0):

In short, **node_modules is a place where all your project dependencies are stored**. And allows you to use these dependencies in the code if you want to and allows for the modules itself to have it own dependencies if any.

And it is very common or rather always the case when a local node_modules folder is created.

You can install dependencies globally by doing `npm install -g module_name` command via your CLI. But these may cause the issue if the global paths are not configured properly.Also, it is not advisable to keep all the required dependencies by an application in global context.

If you do not want some dependencies to be part of your production environment you can install them as dev dependencies via `npm install--save-dev module_name` command. These(normal & dev dependencies) will be installed when a developer clones your project and run npm install locally to run the project and run tests. But to ignore these from being installed on production you can execute `npm install --production` command, this will make sure that only dependencies required for your code to run will be installed in the node_modules folder.